# How to read binary data from xhr response

Tags: javascript, binaryfiles, tibco-business-works

Using javascript.
I'am sending an xhr request to a server, so I receive an xhr response, which contains a multipart data, the second part contains downloadable file (pdf,png,office documents)

in the xhr.response I got this:

```
--_NextPart_000_0002_01C3E1CC.3BB37320
Content-type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
<ns0:sendAttachmentOutput xmlns:ns0="http://****/webservices/definition/BDS/AttachmentFileStorage/sendAttachmentOutput/1">
    <ns0:msgCode>BDS0000</ns0:msgCode>
    <ns0:msgLibelle>Pièce jointe envoyée</ns0:msgLibelle>
</ns0:sendAttachmentOutput>
--_NextPart_000_0002_01C3E1CC.3BB37320
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="testsza.xlsx"
Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

PK     ! |lؖl     [Content_Types].xml (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ]Kðǯ��4٦Ɉ۝珈Ω֦!'ܛ࠷4zԐ杷}Ҵ఼jLքZق��`KǴݕ�՟ҌôJg k@6]^ȫّ؅Õ1̡҈݇K3Ջ͌��̲.g ޞͨݍ`c[
6>@%&fϫ`ѥ��̠ӻċʔ,κ擯8uƚ̵ǫàÓ]��Ԃl"C|֍aȕ.͟ݛԮ˴ ʕˆv# ֠ѱ<ͼҚi蟙ŝ_>ң퟿�����$I爁`\3ж#z̹ցիԔgĮѤ8ϔ(N߅]d՝٧!Qþ4ڮࠞҒ鵃oןڼS:݅˗ѧ   ��PK     ! ֕0#��L   _rels/.rels (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ̒ЎðǯH݃弪nHe܌HۡT$ͣ$@��Êcܑ��[߮窔b/Nú(Aѳb{تx͟Vb"giǚΜaWޞl_xĔܢػȲˋڔ��OѰQˡhѓɥܔ彆ߞP-<ցj{ʾ״Mox/羢؎̀ޓ;̶愦ʏۨۂ̉Õʻ"cަۜO��q"KʐH᳼ߊs@쫁.ࠨʸގ<⧄⎤T_   ��PK     ! މ��  ԃ   xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ܓЪðǯýđ}qӮeԺ݌AЛ��㑄6׶'o?ԃۀɮWä��ȽᨯėjޕХ)ԥۨ̚<àֶҝӨ`@ÃqؿĎs$%Ǚ襤Ӡϩqmݔ.��궹֍ʼMײ��ƩΕð̶ NÏ
--_NextPart_000_0002_01C3E1CC.3BB37320
```

I want to extract the binary data which starts from PK.

here is the code I wrote:

```
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            var arraybuffer = xhr.response;
            var fileArray = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
 var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
            var boundary;
            if (type.indexOf('boundary') != -1) {
                boundary = type.substring(type.indexOf('boundary') + 9);
            }
            var temp = holder.split('--' + boundary);
            var parts = [];
            //loop through array to remove empty parts
            for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                if (temp[i] != "") {
                    parts.push(temp[i]);
                }
            }

var type = parts[2].substring(parts[2].lastIndexOf('Content-type: ') + 14, parts[2].indexOf('\n', parts[2].lastIndexOf('Content-type: ')) - 1);
                var filename = parts[2].substring(parts[2].indexOf('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="') + 43, parts[2].indexOf('\n', parts[2].indexOf('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="')) - 2);
                var lastBoundary = holder.lastIndexOf(boundary) - 4;
                //PARSE SECOND PART

                //var fileStart = holder.indexOf('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="') + 43 + filename.length + 5;
```

//***** fileStart should have the index of the begining of the binary data, othehrwise it should begin from 'PK', just after the content-type line

```
                //start point to the end of the array
                var file = fileArray.buffer.slice(fileStart, lastBoundary);

                if (!file || 0 === file.byteLength) {
                    _displayError("Pdf introuvable");
                }
                else if (type == "text/html;charset=UTF-8") {
                    _displayError("Erreur de téléchargement du pdf. Veuillez contacter l'administrateur.");
                }
                else {
                    var blob = new Blob([file],
                    {
                        type: type
                    });
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you downloading what actually is multipart body that often are sent to server?

Answer (score 0):

I found the right filestart expression:

```
var fileStart = holder.indexOf('Content-type: ', holder.indexOf('Content-disposition: ')) + type.length +18;
```